# React Native with CSS Framework?

Tags: css, react-native

I'm newbie for React Native and trying to use CSS Framework listed in the following link:

http://react.rocks/tag/CSSFramework

I just follow README for React but it has error on terminal saying:-

```
Error: Cannot find package main file for package: /Users/kamesho/git/Chifan/node_modules/reactify/node_modules/react-tools/src
at DependecyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/kamesho/git/Chifan/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:229:13)
at /Users/kamesho/git/Chifan/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:122:22
at Array.forEach (native)
at collect (/Users/kamesho/git/Chifan/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:120:25)
at /Users/kamesho/git/Chifan/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:135:9
at Array.forEach (native)
at collect (/Users/kamesho/git/Chifan/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:120:25)
at /Users/kamesho/git/Chifan/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:135:9
at Array.forEach (native)
at collect (/Users/kamesho/git/Chifan/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:120:25)
at /Users/kamesho/git/Chifan/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:135:9
at Array.forEach (native)
at collect (/Users/kamesho/git/Chifan/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:120:25)
at DependecyGraph.getOrderedDependencies (/Users/kamesho/git/Chifan/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:141:3)
at /Users/kamesho/git/Chifan/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/index.js:91:35
at tryCatcher (/Users/kamesho/git/Chifan/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:24:31)
```

I tried to install react-tools and add to package.json but no luck..

Is it possible to use these CSS Framework on React Native?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React and React Native are very different beasts. React operates on the browser's DOM. RN doesn't do that, it builds up its own model of your UI with iOS views.

Given that knowledge, a CSS framework usable for web-React would have no use in React Native, since there is no browser DOM for it to style.